# Shiny drop down selection as input to filter

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the tree type selected in a drop down to filter a data frame.

I have created a simple stand alone version below.
Right now, "maple" is hard coded as the tree to filter by. I would like to filter by whatever the user selects in the drop down.

Clearly, I'm new to shiny and would like to know what variable to use in replace of "maple".

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr) # Needed for filter

# Read tree types
data  <- c("oak", "maple", "elm")

# Read clean list of all Toronto's trees
tree_clean <- tibble (
  type = c("oak", "oak", "elm", "maple", "maple", "maple"),
  size = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30),
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)

function(input, output, session){

  my_list <- reactive({
    my_list <- as.character(data)

  })

  output$tree <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "tree", label = "Select a Tree", choices = my_list())
  })

  get_tree_data <- reactive({
    filter(tree_clean, type == "maple") 
  })



  observe({
  tree_data <- get_tree_data()
  print(tree_data)


  })

}
```

ui.R

```
# Scrollable dropdown with 246 tree names
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Toronto Tree Map")

body <- dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
            column(width = 9,
                   box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE)
                  ),

            column(width = 3,
                   box(width = NULL,
                       uiOutput(outputId = "tree")
                   )
            )
      )    
)

dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)
```

OLD QUESTION --------------------------------------------

In Server.R I thought replacing the hardcoded, "Japanese Katsura" with input$tree would work. However, it gives the error:

```
Warning in is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Warning: Error in filter_impl: Result must have length 567061, not 0
```

What variable should I replace the hardcoded "Japanese Katsura" with so that my filter is fed by the user's selection in the drop down?

Server.R

```
# Scrollable dropdown with 246 tree names linked to map 
library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr) # Needed for filter

# Read border of Toronto
to_border <- st_read("citygcs_regional_mun_wgs84.shp", quiet = TRUE)
border  <-  to_border %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")

# Read list of Toronto's 246 tree types
data <- read.csv("common_tree_names_246.csv", header = FALSE)$V1

# Read clean list of all Toronto's trees
tree_clean <- st_read("trees_lower_case6.shp")

function(input, output, session){

  my_list <- reactive({
    my_list <- as.character(data)

  })

  output$tree <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "tree", label = "Select a Tree", choices = my_list())
  })

  get_tree_data <- reactive({
    filter(tree_clean, tname == "Japanese Katsura") 
  })


  # Call once since using Leaflet proxy
  output$torontoMap<-renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 10, maxZoom = 18), width = "100%") %>%
      addTiles() %>%

      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Watercolor) %>%

      # Centre the map in the middle of Toronto
      setView(lng = -79.384293, 
      lat = 43.685, #43.653908, 
      zoom = 12)
  })

  observe({
  tree_data <- get_tree_data()
  print(nrow(tree_data))

    # If the data changes, the polygons are cleared and redrawn, however, the map (above) is not redrawn
    leafletProxy("torontoMap", data = tree_data) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%

      addCircles(data = tree_data,
                 color = "green",
                 weight = 5)
  })

}
```

UI.R

```
# Scrollable dropdown with 246 tree names
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

# Remember   verbatimTextOutput("selection")

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Toronto Tree Map")

body <- dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
            column(width = 9,
                   box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
                       leafletOutput("torontoMap", height = 400)
                      )
                  ),

            column(width = 3,
                   box(width = NULL,
                       uiOutput(outputId = "tree")
                   )
            )
      )    
)

dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)
```

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you make your question small and reproducible by only including the UI and Server elements required to replicate your issue, and providing a small data set with your question.

Comment: Point taken. See revised question.

Comment: You're very close; you need to check for a `null` input (which it will be when the shiny loads), so inside your `reactive()`, use `if(is.null(input$tree)) return()`. Then your `filter(tree_clean, type == input$tree)` will work.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Has it solved your issue or is it still not working?

Comment: Yes it's working nicely. Thank-you very much.